# How can I upgrade KDE 4.9 in Kubuntu 11.10?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, kde

If it's possible, how can I upgrade KDE 4.9 in Kubuntu 11.10 ?

I added the backports but nothing new.

Answer (score 1):

**Kubuntu 11.10 support**

The Kubuntu 11.10 will get bug fixes and security patches for the KDE 4.7.4: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59191-Will-there-be-KDE-4-8-4-updates-or-backports-for-oneiric

The Kubuntu 11.10 will be supported to the 2013-04: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu

**Kubuntu and the KDE 4.9**

The KDE SC 4.9.0 is available for the Kubuntu 12.10 (under development) and the Kubuntu 12.04: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.9

> Packages for the release of KDE's Plasma and Applications 4.9 are
>   available for Kubuntu 12.04. You can get it from the Kubuntu Backports
>   PPA. They are also in our development release...